# parentheses before function syntax js meaning

Tags: javascript

I came across with a piece of code with new syntax for me, What this syntax means in js? I mean this parentheses at the beginning:

```
(function () {
   //...
})()
```

Comment: it's a function that will execute immediately when the script loads

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Immediately Invoked Function Express, also knows as an IIFE (pronounced as *iffy*)

Comment: please first google about it, it is a common knowledge which you will find everywhere. Which saves everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

basically, you can define a a function and invoke it immediately without declaring a name for it.